# CSV download on Mac - no file name and extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, csv, browser

I have a following part of code which works great on Windows browsers, but it fails on Mac browsers:

```
    csvData = "data:application/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(tableString);

    $(event.target).attr(
    {
        "href": csvData,
        "target": "_blank",
        "download": tableId+".csv"
    });
```

It suppose to download my html table to csv with proper name, but instead on Mac it download a file with name "Unknown" and no csv extension. Is there any solution to fix this?

JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/77q6e355/)

Comment: Can you specify which browser? Usually Macs handle file downloads better than Windows to be honest, so this is odd!

Comment: @ChrisChinchilla I tested it on Safari.

Comment: Do you have the code somewhere testable? It could be something to do with the data, but hard to know with this out of context code snippet. Even a JS fiddle or something like that

Comment: You can try this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/77q6e355/)